# How to handle row double click in GridView?

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I have a DevExpress GridControl. I want to handle a row doubleclicks with it. I do:

```
        private void УчасткиGridControlDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridControl grid = sender as GridControl;
        DXMouseEventArgs args = e as DXMouseEventArgs;
        var hitInfo = grid.Views[0].CalcHitInfo(args.Location) as GridHitInfo;

        MessageBox.Show(hitInfo.HitTest.ToString());
    }
```

But i get message only if click on Row Indicator or Column Header.
How to handle clicks on row's cells?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you should Handle  [**GridView.DoubleClick**](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_DoubleClicktopic)

```
private void УчасткиGridControlDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {

GridView view = (GridView)sender;

Point pt = view.GridControl.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);

DoRowDoubleClick(view, pt);

}

   private static void DoRowDoubleClick(GridView view, Point pt) {

GridHitInfo info = view.CalcHitInfo(pt);

if(info.InRow || info.InRowCell) {

    string colCaption = info.Column == null ? "N/A" : info.Column.GetCaption();

    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("DoubleClick on row: {0}, column: {1}.", info.RowHandle, colCaption));

}
```

For more please refer to [Devexpress Double Click](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A2934)

**Note:** This code works only when your grid is *not editable*